# Paho Python client is encountering a socket read error and subsequent disconnect from broker

Tags: python, ssl, rabbitmq, paho

Client details: Paho MQTT Python client obtained from http://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/paho/org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.python.git, SHA id 300fcbdffd62d08f627f94f3074463cfa532ca87

Broker details: RabbitMQ 3.3.4 with the MQTT plugin

In the first scenario everything is being run locally with SSL enabled. I am using the client in a fashion where I have a separate process which publishes messages (> 10000 messages) and does not wait for an acknowledgment between publishes. The error is a result of the self._ssl.read(1) returning a a zero length value from the following code snippet from _packet_read in client.py:

```
        ...
        if self._in_packet['command'] == 0:
        try:
            if self._ssl:
                command = self._ssl.read(1)
            else:
                command = self._sock.recv(1)
        except socket.error as err:
        ...
        else:
            if len(command) == 0:
                return 1
            command = struct.unpack("!B", command)
            self._in_packet['command'] = command[0]
        ...
```

and occurs after receiving and parsing 25 acknowledgments from RabbitMQ. After this error I no longer receive anything back from the broker.

If I run with SSL disabled I do not encounter any errors and can successfully receive acknowledgements for all messages sent.

If I run the broker remotely (some location on the internet) I get the same results over SSL. However, when not using SSL I get the read error/disconnect at different intervals but the client is able to recover/reconnect and I receive broker acknowledgements for all messages sent.

Here is the client configuration that I'm using:

```
    ...
    client = Client('foo')
    client.max_inflight_messages_set(65536)
    client.on_connect = self.on_connect_callback
    client.on_disconnect = self.on_disconnect_callback
    client.on_publish = self.on_publish_callback
    client.on_message = self.on_message_callback
    client.username_pw_set('foo', 'bar')
    client.tls_set("ca-cert.pem",
                        "client-cert.pem",
                        "client-key.pem")
    client.will_set(topic="last_will/foo",
                         payload=Message().body, qos=1)
    client.connect('127.0.0.1', 8883, 30)
    client.loop_start()
    ...
```

Any idea on what could be causing this and/or suggestions for troubleshooting?

UPDATE 20140828: I was stepping through the loop_read and noticed that I get an empty socket return value after successfully receiving the first full packet (the connection acknowledgment). The call to select that precedes the socket.recv call indicates that there is data ready to be read on the socket. Could this be a socket buffer issue? I'm not sure what the behavior of a Python socket receive buffer (btw I'm running this on OSX) is if it overflows.